# Update table using Openquery linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, openquery

I've tried this code and still got the following error, perhaps anyone could help?

```
UPDATE a 
SET    a.MMDWNO = '21'
FROM   OPENQUERY(NMIIFLIB,
       'select * from MVXCDTANSN.MITMAS WHERE MMITTY = ''25''') a
```

Error :

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NMIIFLIB" returned
>   message "[IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL7008 - MITMAS in
>   MVXCDTANSN not valid for operation.".
>   Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NMIIFLIB"
>   could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]".

The select statement works fine but when I try to update I always stuck with this.

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to update a table on linked server, try this syntax:

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(NMIIFLIB, 'select * from MVXCDTANSN.MITMAS where MMITTY = ''25''')
SET MMDWNO = 21
```

Answer (score -2):

you must try this. Hope this will help you.

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(firstlink, 'select * from job.dbo.student where id = ''3''') 
    SET name = 'sanjeev acharya'
```